# Calculating The Date Using Day of Week Month And Year in Apex

Tags: apex, date

My question is different than the other date questions Ive seen here. I'm trying to calculate all of the dates using Day, Month and Year inputs. Right now I'm using a Custom Setting but think might be able to use Apex which would be much better. Needs to include leap years of course.

Input fields: Day, Month, Year
Ex: Monday, June, 2013

Expected Output:
June 3, 2013
June 10, 2013
June 17, 2013
June 24, 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class myDateClass{

    static map<string,integer> dowMap = new map<string,integer>{'Monday'=>0,
                                                                'Tuesday'=>1,
                                                                'Wednesday'=>2,
                                                                'Thursday'=>3,
                                                                'Friday'=>4,
                                                                'Saturday'=>5,
                                                                'Sunday'=>6};                                                           

    public static list<date> getMyDates(string dayOfWeekName, integer month, integer year){
        list<date> returnList = new list<date>();
        date d = date.newInstance(year,month,1);
        d=d.addDays(math.mod(7-dayOfWeek(d)+dowMap.get(dayOfWeekName),7));//brings you to the first instance of the specified dayOfWeekName of the month

        do{
            returnList.add(d);
            d=d.addDays(7);
        } while(d.month()==month);

        return returnList;
    }

    public static integer dayOfWeek(date d){
        return math.mod(date.newInstance(1900,1,8).daysBetween(d),7); 
    }
}
```

Example:

```
list<date> dates = myDateClass.getMyDates('Monday',4,2013);
for(date d:dates)
    system.debug(d);
```

*Output*:

```
15:53:22:067 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|2013-04-01 00:00:00
15:53:22:067 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|2013-04-08 00:00:00
15:53:22:067 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|2013-04-15 00:00:00
15:53:22:067 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|2013-04-22 00:00:00
15:53:22:068 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|2013-04-29 00:00:00
```

If you need a special date format in a Visualforce page, you can use `apex:outputText`

E.g.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,EEEE MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}">
    <apex:param value="{!myDate}" /> 
</apex:outputText>
```

Outputs:

```
Wednesday 6/26/2013
```

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with each of those but question is figuring out the dates with the input listed. Different than what you have listed.

Comment: well, what's your formula for determining those dates?   
is your question what are all the days in a month that lie on a specific day of the week?

Comment: post edited.  is this what you were looking for?

Comment: This edited myDateclass seems to be exactly it!